# CompositeDisposable cause memory leaks until clear or dispose called?

Tags: java, android, rx-java2

Every `Disposable` added to the `CompositeDisposable` will strong referenced by `CompositeDisposable` until `CompositeDisposable` cleared or disposed. This will prevent objects strong referenced by subscriber(Disposable) to be collected.

Should I wrap all the `Disposable` into `WeakReference` before add to `CompositeDisposable`? or just ignore and let `CompositeDisposable` got cleared in future.

Comment: The scope of CompositeDisposable is generally kept same as of those variables used inside subscribe(). Means each activity has its own compositeDisposable object to manage disposables. So that won't result into memory leak.

Comment: @GauravChauhan Sorry for late reply. But the subscriber object itself own't be auto removed from CompositeDisposable, and developer must care of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upstream strong reference to downstream when subscribed.
The final **Disposable** **Observer** still be able disposed by this container when upstream not finished the task.

```
import io.reactivex.disposables.Disposable
import io.reactivex.exceptions.CompositeException
import io.reactivex.internal.disposables.DisposableContainer
import java.util.*
import kotlin.collections.ArrayList

class WeakDisposableContainer : DisposableContainer, Disposable {

    private val container = WeakHashMap<Disposable, Any>()

    @Volatile
    private var disposed = false

    override fun add(d: Disposable): Boolean {
        if (!disposed) {
            synchronized(this) {
                if (!disposed) {
                    container[d] = Unit
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        d.dispose()
        return false
    }

    override fun remove(d: Disposable): Boolean {
        if (delete(d)) {
            d.dispose()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    override fun delete(d: Disposable): Boolean {
        if (disposed) return false
        synchronized(this) {
            if (disposed) return false
            return container.remove(d) != null
        }
    }

    override fun isDisposed(): Boolean = disposed

    override fun dispose() {
        clear()
        disposed = true
    }

    fun clear() {
        if (disposed) return
        val d: Iterable<Disposable>
        synchronized(this) {
            if (disposed) return
            d = ArrayList(container.keys)
            container.clear()
        }
        val err = d.mapNotNull { catchThrowable { it.dispose() } }
        if (err.isNotEmpty()) throw CompositeException(err)
    }
}
```

```
inline fun catchThrowable(block: () -> Unit): Throwable? = try {
    block()
    null
} catch (e: Throwable) {
    e
}
```